# Does ADXL 345 accelerometer not wirk with Arduino Uno without soldering?

Tags: arduino-uno

I followed the Adafruit tutorials to wire the ADXL 345 with Ardiuno Uno, but it is not able to detect the sensor.  It did not mention that I need to solder the ADXL 345.  Is soldering necessary?

Comment: The ADXL345 is a chip. Did you buy a chip, or did you buy a module with the chip on? Are you referring to the header pins that some modules come with? If so then yes of course they need to be soldered in.

Comment: If you could follow completely through the adafruit tutorial, then most likely that is not the problem. This sounds like an X-Y problem. You are asking about soldering because you think that might be a problem. Though the real problem might be somewhere else. Please include a wiring diagram of your real setup (not the tutorial), your code, a description of what behavior you expected vs what actually happened and a description, of what you have tried to track down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some boards and wires are built so that plugging them together should work fine.  For example the following picture [from embedded.com](https://www.embedded.com/building-arduino-breadboards-without-jumper-wires/) of an Arduino, ready made wires with pins at the ends and a bread board should connect with no soldering:

[image]

And if your [Analog Devices ADXL-350 chip](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adxl350.html#product-overview) is already soldered onto a [PCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board) with 1/10 inch headers as in this picture [from Adafruit.com](https://www.adafruit.com/):

[image]

... you should be able to connect the Arduino to the accelerometer with out soldering.

However, if the header and ADXL-450 PCB from Adafruit are not soldered together, as is the case in this picture:
[image]

... you will have to solder them as outlined on [this Adafruit web page](https://learn.adafruit.com/adxl345-digital-accelerometer/assembly-and-wiring).